# Running code metrics in builds for TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, code-metrics

How do I get metrics to run with my builds in TFS 2012?

I have not seen any solutions for Code Metrics inside of TFS 2012. Microsoft's Metrics tool appears to only work with TFS 2010. The main things I am looking for are the very things that Microsoft's tool used to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code Metrics for both Visual Studio 2005, 2008, 2010 and 2012 are pretty much the same. You can access them from the 'Analysis" menu in Visual Studio and they give you a view on your code to help you identify specific thing you might want to fix.

This has never been available as part of an automated build and really makes no sense there as they are interpretive and not descriptive. Just because you have a high Cyclomatic complexity does not mean your code is bad.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385911.aspx

It may be useful for you to explain what you are trying to achieve so that I can better point you to a solution.

- **What value are you trying to achieve?**

There does seem to be a [CodeMetric](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20integrate%20the%20codemetric%20build%20activity&referringTitle=Documentation) build activity as part of the [Community TFS Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/) but I am not sure if it does what you want.

Comment: The exact things that you get from running through Visual Studio, but as part of the automated build. Basically, a lot of our developers are wanting to see these things without having to run it locally. It therefore would make such statistics public as part of the build process and also automate their creation for the developer.

Comment: There does sema to be a CodeMetric build activity as part of the Community TFS Build Extensions but I am not sure if it does what you want. I added links to the answer above...

Comment: It does make sense for a lot of us to have code metrics as a part of CI.
I see it is a very good instrument to improve the code quality.
Actually so important that it could be a tipping point for reaplacing Team foundation server.

Comment: You do know that you can plug tools like Sonar into any build system to get that sort of analysis? I don't believe any build system provides OOB Code Analysis and instead rely on plugins.